# Ionic set localvariable if Http Request doesnt return null

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, subscribe

i've a Database table named users and i wanna check if email exists before adding a row.
I created a local variable named emailTaken and initialized it to 0, and i made a function that does a http get request to get the user row using the entered email (It does select * from users where email=...), and i subscribed returned data, then if the returned data is not null it means that there's already someone with that Email ans i set my Local Variable to 1 but it doesnt changes here's my function:

```
checkIfExistEmail(){
var tocheck;
var check = this.authServiceProvider.getData("userbymail/" + this.userData.email);
check.subscribe(
  data => {
    if(data != null){
      this.emailTaken = 1;
console.log("inside function: "+this.emailTaken); // this is showing 1
    }
  },
  err => {
    console.error("Something went wrong", err);
  })
  }
```

Here's the getData function:

```
public getData(type): Observable<any> {

return this.http.get(apiUrl + type);


}
```

how im using checkIfExistEmail() in my Signup Page:

```
export class SignupPage {
.....
.....
.....
public emailTaken;
.....
.....
.....
goEtape2(){
this.emailTaken=0;
this.checkIfExistEmail();
console.log("email: "+this.emailTaken);// this is showing 0
}
```

When i call to goEtape2 function i get this in console

```
email: 0
inside function: 1
```

Comment: I'm assuming this question is about the Angular framework and not AngularJS? If so, please remove the angularjs tag.

Comment: @DavidWalschots yea sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getData is asynchronous. So the subscription block and the line `this.emailTaken = 1;` are executed later then the `console.log("email: "+this.emailTaken);`

You have to deal with the asynchronous events correctly.

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/switchmap"

checkIfExistEmail(){
  var tocheck;
  var check = this.authServiceProvider.getData("userbymail/" + this.userData.email);
  return check.switchMap(
    data => Observable.of((data != null) ? true : false),  
    err => console.error("Something went wrong", err)
  );
}
```

Now `checkIfExistEmail` is also observable and returns an boolean observable that tells you if an email address exists or not. The subscription guarantees that the `if (emailTaken) ...` part is executed after the http response is received.

```
this.checkIfExistEmail().subscribe((emailTaken) =>{
  if (emailTaken){
    // email is already in use
  }else{
    // go on
  }
});
```

Comment: Same, its not working the local variable value isnt changing

Comment: I made a console.log(this.emailTaken) inside the getData, its changing but when going out of the function it gets back to 0, tried to make it return the 1 but it doesnt returns it too

Comment: do you mix up async and sync? is the return executed before the subscription is hit? can you give the complete code with the return and comments where it used to be 1 and it's still 0